# I want to show a list item's index in a loop

Tags: c#, .net, algorithm, indexing, windows-forms-designer

```
        List<string> lst = new List<string>() { "mahdi","arshia","amir"};

        int a = 0;
        var list_mian = lst[a];

        for (int i = a; i <Convert.ToInt16(list_mian); i++) //Additional information: Input string was not in a correct format.
        {
            MessageBox.Show(lst.IndexOf(lst[0]).ToString());
        }
```

I want to show a list item's index in a loop, for example of mahdi's index is 0 and amir's index is 2 i wanna show their index respectively in a "for" loop and i give an error that i show that in the code part

Comment: The error is coming from `Convert.ToInt16(list_mian)` … `list_mian = lst[0]` … which is the `string` “mahdi” … that is not a valid `int` value… hence the error. Your question is odd in a sense that if you ONLY want to display the “indexes” in the list, then a simple loop from zero (0) to the size of the list is all that is needed. … `for (int i = 0; i < lst.Count; i++) { MessageBox.Show(i); }`

Answer (score 0):

Your trying to convert an integer to a string and then use that as a range on the for loop just use .count and compare it to the name attached to that index of the list. Hope you find this useful.

```
    public static int? findPerson(string name)
    {
        List<string> lst = new List<string>() { "mahdi", "arshia", "amir" };
        int? result = null;
        for (int i = 0; i < lst.Count; i++) //Additional information: Input string was not in a correct format.
        {
            if (lst[i] == name)
            {
                result = i;
            }
        }
        return result;
    }
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var index = findPerson("arshia");
        if (index == null)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("PersonNotFound");
        }
        else {
            Console.WriteLine("Index of " + index.ToString());
        
        }
    }
```

Comment: no i wanna  show their number of index not the item's.

Comment: Oh I see you want to find the index of the name that your putting in.

Comment: Make sure that you have read the question completely and carefully

Comment: You can plug whatever value you want into that function. Although LINQ is probably worth the time investment to understand if your going to find yourself trying to sort lists often.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with **IndexOf** it returns the index or -1 when there is no item.

```cs
List<string> list = new List<string>() { "mahdi", "arshia", "amir" };
var indexOfAmir = list.IndexOf("amir"); // 2
var indexOfMax = list.IndexOf("max"); // -1
```